# Android Espresso Testing Grant Permissions

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have an application that uses the READ_CONTACTS permission. This permission is asked for as soon as the application starts. I'm am wanting this permission to be accepted automatically when performing automated testing with espresso. I have tried using a `GrantPermissionRule`. the rule works for all the other permissions I need, but not for READ_CONTACTS. I have also tried using UiAnimator, but this also has not worked. I'm trying the UiAnimator method at the start of each test, but it won't run until I manually accept the permission shown on the screen. How can I get this permission accepted automatically?

```
public static void allowPermissionsIfNeeded()  {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
        UiObject rational = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Yes"));
        if (rational.exists()) {
            try {
                rational.click();
            } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                Timber.e(e, "There is no permissions dialog to interact with ");
            }
        }
        UiObject allowPermissions = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Allow"));
        if (allowPermissions.exists()) {
            try {
                allowPermissions.click();
            } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                Timber.e(e, "There is no permissions dialog to interact with ");
            }
        }
    }
}


@Rule
public GrantPermissionRule grantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be lacking a method annotated with `@Before`; as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule) reads:

> Static factory method that grants the requested permissions.
>
> Permissions will be granted before any methods annotated with `@Before`
>
> but before any test method execution.

(I have to admit, that I don't really understand the "but" there either).